# Why does my file get null in Java?

Tags: java

Trying to read in a maze in from a textfile to Java.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Maze { 
    private char[][]mazeData;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Maze test = new Maze();
    }
    public Maze() { 
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            File f = new File("c://testing.txt");
            String line = null;
            int row = 0;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            reader.mark((int)f.length());
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 line = reader.readLine();
                 row++;
            }
            reader.reset();
            mazeData = new char[row][];
            row = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                mazeData[row++] = line.toCharArray();
            }
            int col=mazeData[0].length;
            for (int i=0; i < row; i++){
                for (int j=0; j < col; j++){
                    System.out.print(mazeData[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            reader.close();

         } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("INVALID FILE");
         }
            }

    }
```

I tested in another class and java could find the file there so i dont get why the exeption keeps happening.

Comment: Does `c://testing.txt` exist? Isn't it `c:\testing.txt`?

Comment: It says INVALID FILE even if i have    File f = new File("C:\testing.txt");

Comment: Try "C:\\testing.txt" or "C:/testing.txt"

Comment: `"C:\testing.txt" has a tab character in it. / Anyway, what's `null`? I ould imagine `mazeData` being an array of `null`s. (`List<>` is your friend.)

Comment: c:\\testing.txt c:/testing.txt both gives me invalid file

Comment: What exception do you get (please copy StackTrace)?

Comment: Just debug your code to get the exact issue. Just curious, what is your ultimate aim. There might be a better solution.

Comment: Using `mark` is not usually the correct way to go. I've never found it useful. For a start, you are comparing octets to characters using an encoding unspecified in this code. Should the `mark` have a `+1`? I don't know. Anyway, as I say, `List<>` should remove the need for this messing about.

Comment: *What* exception keeps happening? NB when you *get* an exception, don't make up your own error messages. Use the one in the exception. Otherwise debugging is just a guessing game.

Comment: instead of reader.mark and reader.reset(), why don't you initialize the reader object again. That will work. :)

Comment: See answer of @SubOptimal. You don't need to count the rows first. Also if you want to do it your way - you will get a wrong result for "row" as your are are calling .readLine() twice per iteration ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would print the catched exception you would read `java.io.IOException: Mark invalid`. Which is thrown at `reader.reset();` because the mark has been invalidated.

You can fix it by

```
reader.mark((int)f.length() + 1);
```

Anyway there is no need to process the file twice only to know the number of lines. You can read all lines into a `List<String>` and process the lines from that array.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("c:/testing.txt"),
    Charset.defaultCharset());
```

**edit**

A stripped down solution (based on your code) could be.

```
public class Maze {

    private char[][] mazeData;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Maze test = new Maze();
    }

    public Maze() {
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("c:/testing.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());

            mazeData = new char[lines.size()][];
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                mazeData[i] = lines.get(i).toCharArray();
            }
            int columns = mazeData[0].length;
            int rows = lines.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    System.out.print(mazeData[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("failed: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Keep few other comments:
- avoid to do I/O processing in a constructor
- split the code in logical blocks (one method per logical step), e.g. initMazed(), printMaze(), etc.

Comment: @Prototype If the posted answer solves your problem you could accept this answer.